# Alternatives to SSL

Tags: security, ssl, https, cryptography

So over the last few years it seems like SSL has taken rather a beating from the security community. While the technical reasons are beyond my understanding, I understand the concepts and understand that SSL is becoming more and more insecure as new weaknesses are found.

My question to you guys is this:
If SSL is "broken", is there a technology that can take its place? Is there a more secure alternative?

Any thoughts are appreciated! :)

(ps, I'm not specifically talking about HTTPS - I mean any SSL technology)

Comment: might be more appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with @Rook answer below. But one very neat alternative worth a look is [CurveCP](http://curvecp.org/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SSL is **not broken**.   The protocol is designed to be robust,  problems can be found in a specific cipher suite,  and a patch is as simple as a one line configuration change using a new one.   There are attacks like [SSLStrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) and ways of preventing it,  such as [HTTP STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

The biggest problem is that people don't use HTTPS often enough.  This leads to problems like [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) which can be exploited by tools like [firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep).

Comment: And the other 'biggest problem' is that programmers deliberatly break the PKI model 'to get it running', e.g. by trusting all server certificates.

Comment: @EJP I disagree.  I think its websites like SO that ignore owasp a9.

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly are you disagreeing with?

Answer (score 8):

I would disagree with the previous responses that SSL is not broken - one of the main issues of late has been CA's (Certificate Authorities) getting compromised.  SSL is designed to use trusted third parties - forever.  If any of those trusted parties become compromised, they have the keys to the castle.

We've already seen a number big name CA's like Comodo and DigiNotar being compromised.  It's become such a large problem that NIST released an [ITL bulletin on how to respond to CA compromises](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistbul/july-2012_itl-bulletin.pdf).  So I would argue that although some implementations of SSL/TLS are still technically sound, the "broken" part is a design issue having to do with the source of "trust."

Comment: SSL/TLS itself doesn't actually depend on PKIX (the usual CA model); as such, it's not broken. Non-SSL security solutions (e.g. message-level security) or home-made alternatives will also have to have a trust aspect, like any security solution. The difficulty is the trust model, which is in fact independent of SSL/TLS and which is mostly a non-technical problem unfortunately. Blaming SSL/TLS and trying to replace it is missing the point completely.

Comment: You're absolutely right in that the SSL/TLS protocals don't require CA's - only authentication of certs in some form.  Furthermore, I'd agree that the trust model is the problem with how SSL/TLS is currently implemented.  I was speaking in light of the general application - SSL/TLS through a web browser with a stock CA list used for authentication.  Perhaps this wasn't specifically what the question was asking, but I was pointing out the need to make changes in what most people refer to as "SSL."

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL does have some insecurities and there is a proposal for fixing them. TACK builds on a technique called pinning that was introduced by Google. Here's the submission to the TLS working group.

http://tack.io/draft.html

Comment: Are you talking about insecurities in OpenSSL, in SSL/TLS or in the CA model? These are different things.

Comment: Although there are some insecurities in OpenSSL, e.g. how common name fields are parsed I was talking about the CA model. TACK helps client certificates know they are talking to the right server.